# parsing value for the same key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
alice_ratings = {"alonzo": 1, "bob": 3, "turing" : 2}
bob_ratings = {"alice": 1, "alonzo": 2, "turing": 3}
alonzo_ratings = {"alice": 3, "bob": 2, "turing": 1}
turing_ratings = {"alice": 2, "alonzo": 1, "bob": 3}
```

corresponding dictionary of student
preferences are given to me,I want write a function that returns a student with the lowest average score, how can I do this.
example: alonzo has a rating of 4 overall,how can I do this can someone help me with this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried creating another dictionary that contains the value for all ,but I cant figure out what to do next ,could you give me an idea at least i am new to python dictionaries

Comment: Can you add some code here and expected output. Here's a link about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you have any other limitations on this task? (like additional memory? or O(n)?)

Comment: Nope I dont have any limitations to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
def lowest(*args):
    ratings = {}
    for d in args:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k in ratings:
                ratings[k] += v
            else:
                ratings[k] = v
    return min(ratings, key=lambda k: ratings[k])
```

OR,

```
from collections import defaultdict

def lowest(*args):
    ratings = defaultdict(int)
    for d in args:
        for k, v in d.items():
            ratings[k] += v

    return min(ratings, key=lambda k: ratings[k])
```

Calling the function:

```
print(lowest(alice_ratings, bob_ratings, alonzo_ratings, turing_ratings))
```

This prints:

```
alonzo
```

Comment: thank you Subham, what if I store all the data in a Dictionary like----------------------------- friends = {"alice": alice_ratings, "bob": bob_ratings, "alonzo": alonzo_ratings, "turing":turing_ratings}        and then call the function with friends as a parameter

Comment: @ShariqShuaib The you can call the function like `lowest(*friends.values())`

Comment: Thank you once again, I did get my output however could you explane me how did you return the value by using $return min(ratings, key=lambda k: ratings[k])$

Comment: Its just returning the key with the minimum value from all the ratings.